# Can't find installed gems

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am very new to ruby, and am using Ubuntu , I installed ruby last week and have been using it ever since. But when I decided to start studying rails I realised the rails server will not start, I decided to reinstall ruby, and then rails, which I did successfully.

But now when I install a ruby gem, I do not see it, not even when I type `gem list` on the terminal, it also throws an error when I try to run it in a program. I am very frustrated and do not know what to do..

Comment: Does `ruby -v` return a version? What kind of error it throws?

Comment: yes ruby -v returns "ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [x86_64-linux]
"

Comment: What is the error you see when running `gem list`?

Comment: no error, only when I try to use the gem that I installed, it tells me that require cannot load such gem

Comment: You do use Gemfile and run your command with `bundle exec`, right? Although this is not strictly necessary it takes care of dependencies.

Comment: naa, I doubt I know how to use Gemfile , I am very new to ruby, so I do not know what that is

Comment: Take a look at the [bundler docs](http://bundler.io/gemfile.html). Otherwise it seems that your ruby process cannot find the gem you want because the path you supply in `require` resolves to something else than the correct one.

Comment: Consider using https://rvm.io right from the start. It basically allows you to install different ruby versions (and gems for that versions) in your home-folder, so you do not need root permissions and can "safely" play around.

Comment: Are you using RVM? RVM takes care of gem installs if you have RVM, and installs gems per user, so using `sudo gem install <gem>` installs the gem for root only, not your user.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing RVM instead of ruby directly, this will install the required setting and it will be easier to beginners.

https://rvm.io/rvm/install